# Programa sencillo en C

Tags: c

Esto lo he quitado de un libro de C antiguo, the C book, estoy aprendiendo c pero no entiendo los dos últimos resultados que da este programa que son un 100 y 99, tampoco entiendo porque retorna el vector de esa forma. 
Muchisimas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int buf[100];
static int length;

static void fillup(void){

    int i = 0;

    while(length < 100){
        buf[length++] = 0;
        i++;
        printf("%d, ",buf[i]);

    }   
}

int callable(){

    if(length == 0){
        fillup();
    }
    return(buf[length--]);          
}

int main(){

    int a;

    a = callable();

    printf("%d\n",a);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yo lo probe y me tira todo ceros

Comment: Ya se cual es el problema, es que te tira datos basura, es porque imprimis el dato siguiente al que fue inicializado

Comment: No son datos basura... El comportamiento correcto es imprimir `0,` hasta el final... donde usa `buf[length--]`, que es realmente el problema, accede al dato `buf[100]` el cual debería ser comportamiento indefinido...

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente funcion tira un valor fuera del array

```
int callable(){

    if(length == 0){
        fillup();
    }
    return(buf[length--]);// Dato basura, ademas de overflow
}
```

La solución si queres que te devuelva el ultimo, primero decrementas length, y luego obtenes el dato del array

```
int callable(){

    if(length == 0){
        fillup();
    }
    return(buf[--length]);
}
```

Espero haber entendido tu problema

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo que se sale de la memoria asignada al vector y tendría que dar un valor basura cualquiera peroa mí siempre me sale el valor 100 y luego al hacer length-- tendría que volver a entrar en el vector y dar  otra vez cero en cambio da 99. Supongo que al salirte del vector ya da un comportamiento indifinido según cada compilador sistema etc. ¿Que opinais? Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En este programa, el problema es que la variable `length` no se inicia. Si pruebas el código en *Windows*, no funcionará. `length` puede ser cualquier valor, y es probable que sea diferente a cero, así que tiene que contar miles de millones de valores hasta llegar a cien.

Se debe iniciar `length` antes de la línea `a = callable()` de la siguiente manera:

```
length = 0;
a = callable();
```